# Aligning pathfinding to the center of tiles?

Tags: unity, path-finding, grid

I'm looking to achieve tile by tile movement in a project I'm working on. I employed the use of the asset Simply A* Path-finding to allow a unit to navigate the terrain.

[image]

[image]

Since the tiles are simply made out of 32x32 sprites, I set the tilesize of the pathfinder to 0.32 to produce the above grid.

However when tested out with a unit, the unit often does not align itself to the center of the sprite as shown in the image below.
[image]

I am pretty new to unity and would appreciate if someone could input on how I can fix this or advise on an alternate method to allow this "tile to tile" path finding to work.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.arongranberg.com/astar/docs/modifiers.php#simplesmooth

If you're using Aron Granberg's pathfinder, then are you perhaps using one of the smoothing modifiers? This would result in the unit trying to optimize the path which would probably prevent the unit from hitting each node as it steps through the path.

Or is the problem that you have a consistent offset when the unit paths from node to node?

Answer (score 0):

You could check to which tile the player is closer to and then just set the position of the player to the centre of the tile.